# Jquery external panel content not appearing correctly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm making a multi-page web app. I want it to have a left and right panel that are available no matter what page you're on. I managed to do that but the contents don't seem like they have the jQuery CSS rules applied to them. I did

```
$("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();
```

And that made my panel work... kinda of the labels for my check marks aren't formatted like they were when the panel wasn't external. I guess I'll just put the code up. I swear I've searched this site forever trying to find answers.

```
$(function () {
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin();         
});

<div data-role="panel" id="RoomInfoPanel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" data-position="right" data-dismissible=false>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2 id="roomNumberHeader">Panel Header..</h2>
        <p class="main" id="CrewText">Crew Assigned:</p>

        <select id="selectCrew" >
            <option>Select Crew</option>
        </select>

        <div id="cblist" style="display:inline">
            <label for="#compChk" class="ui-content">Completed</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="compChk" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="first checkbox" id="paidChk" />
            <label for="#paidChk">Paid</label>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main">
            <a href="#myCrewPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Edit Crews</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#` in `for` attribute. It should be `for="checkboxID"` without hash.